# What is the appropiate way to use money in the past?

Tags: time-travel

Assuming time travelling is possible and there are no fancy regulations, what would be the best way to take this time's money with me to buy things in some time/place in the past?

I'm asking this because money has serial numbers and the like.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the real-world implications of time travel

Comment: I would say this is too opinion-based unless you narrow the scope to a specific story or universe where this problem is evident.

Comment: Collect money with the dates you require for time travel. If you are going back more than 100 years you probably just need gold or silver coins or bars. If you do travel back in time, please buy some Coca Cola stock for me circa 1919.

Comment: @Richard How is that off topic?  Dealing with nitty-gritty implications of time travel seems on topic to me.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Anything prior to about 1945 and you could simply print the money yourself on an inkjet printer.

Comment: @Keen While "on-topic" could be debated, it's definitely opinion-based. SF&F.SE is most competent when dealing with questions about existing stories. This question is asking for pure speculation divorced from any story, so answers would not be supportable with evidence (or, obviously, experience) and instead are purely opinion-based. If it were a question about how to carry currency to the past in *Back the Future* or *Timeline*, it'd be much more answerable within the ethos of the Stack Exchange.

Comment: I would carry gold and gems... really anything that isn't some sort of promissory note, printed money.

Answer (score 2):

The way I have read it in every time travel story that deals with this issue is that the smart traveller goes to a coin collector shop and buys coins and notes valid in the era he or she is travelling to.

Failing that, you would bring bits of gold and gems to sell for local currency.

Comment: Doc Brown in *Back to the Future 2*, for example, had a briefcase full of valid currencies for various time frames.  It's not clear if he did the coin collector method of procuring it.

Comment: @keen - http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110817162516/bttf/images/7/7f/Emergency_cash_suitcase_opened.png